# perform action when application is uninstall

Tags: java, android, uninstallation

How to invoke `setlogout()` when application is uninstalled?

```
    private void setlogout() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URLs.logout+user.getapi_token(),
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
        //adding our stringrequest to queue
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: You cannot get control when your application is uninstalled

Comment: After the application is installed the data is removed from storage and memory and you cannot perform any action when app is installed

Answer (score 2):

Its not feasible, since uninstallation of app is handled by OS.